# A component is changing a controlled input of type undefined to be uncontrolled, why am I getting this?

Tags: reactjs

```
const Message = () => {

    const [message, setMessage] = useState({ recipient: '', textmessage: ''})

    const sendText = () => {

        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:4000/send-text?recipient=${message.recipient}&textmessage=${message.textmessage}`)
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
        console.log("Send Text is Running")
      }


      // console.log(message.recipient);
      // console.log(message.textmessage);



    return (
        <div>
            <h2> Send Text Message </h2>
          <label> Your Phone Number </label>
          <br />
          <input value={message.recipient}
            onChange={e => setMessage({recipient: e.target.value})} />
          <div/>
          <label> Message </label>
          <br />
          <textarea rows={3} value={message.textmessage}
            onChange={e => setMessage({textmessage: e.target.value })} />
          <div/>
          <button onClick={sendText}> Send Text </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Message;
```

When I input the number to update {message.recipient}, it's all good, but when I input on the textbox, to update the {message.textmessage} state, I get that error message.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain the state. What you are doing here is losing the data that is previously set in the state while calling to `setMessage`.

You can do it this,

```
const Message = () => {

    const [message, setMessage] = useState({ recipient: '', textmessage: ''})

    const sendText = () => {

        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:4000/send-text?recipient=${message.recipient}&textmessage=${message.textmessage}`)
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
        console.log("Send Text is Running")
      }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2> Send Text Message </h2>
          <label> Your Phone Number </label>
          <br />
          <input value={message.recipient}
            onChange={e => setMessage({ ...message, recipient: e.target.value})} />
          <div/>
          <label> Message </label>
          <br />
          <textarea rows={3} value={message.textmessage}
            onChange={e => setMessage({ ...message, textmessage: e.target.value })} />
          <div/>
          <button onClick={sendText}> Send Text </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I will really appreciate if you can accept this answer.

Comment: I had the same error and was confused by this answer. It would be helpful to specifically say that React is throwing the error because the OP was (inadvertently) setting the input components' values to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Muhammad Zeeshan answer,

When we are developing class based components, we will use setState to update the state.
Here State will be maintained.

```
state = {
   recipient: '', 
   textmessage: ''
};

onChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({recipent: event.target.value}); // here other state variables will be preserved
}
```

But with React Hooks, State will not be maintained. We have to manually preserve the other state variables.

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState({ recipient: '', textmessage: ''})
...
<input value={message.recipient}
            onChange={e => setMessage({...message, recipient: e.target.value})} />
---
---
<textarea rows={3} value={message.textmessage}
            onChange={e => setMessage({...message, textmessage: e.target.value })} />
```